# Is firebase storage good place to store images that are used on web pages?

Tags: firebase, performance, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, cdn

Should I consider using Firebase Storage for storing images that are rendered on web pages? These might be images rendered on the product listing page or other resources like hero images.
Is image CDN a good option instead of firebase storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I consider using firebase storage for storing images that are rendered on web pages?

Yes. More than that, you can save the image URLs in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) for later use.

> These might be images rendered on the product listing page or other resources like hero images.

Yes, it's a quite common approach.

> Is image CDN a good option instead of Firebase Storage?

There are many options available out there. Besides that, questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries are forbidden, here on Stackoverflow. But what I can tell you, is Firebase Storage will work perfectly fine to display images on a web page.